# How to change the inside color of an open font with css?

Tags: html, css, fonts

I'm playing around with this font in css:
http://www.dafont.com/pix-lite.font

Is it possible to change the the inside color of it using just css?
I'm attaching a picture where I did what I'm looking for manually for reference.

This is what I want to do with css:
http://s9.postimg.org/7jp7b9pa7/Skive_2015_03_06_10_56_09.png

Comment: I doubt that is possible, since "the inside" is nothing that is defined here. It is just an optical effect, but nothing technical. Obviously you can set a background color, but no a different one for inside and outside. You could try to experiment with embedding the same glyph again as "inside" of each character, and use a different background color for that. But such an approach would be a pain to compute.

Answer (score 0):

This is the closest I think you will get to having a text border.

http://jsfiddle.net/recwq5bg/

```
someElement {
    text-shadow: 2px 0 0 #f00, -2px 0 0 #f00, 0 2px 0 #f00, 0 -2px 0 #f00, 1px 1px #f00, -1px -1px 0 #f00, 1px -1px 0 #f00, -1px 1px 0 #f00;
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what happend with that font but it would help you: [fiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/ewfm9e5n/)

```
span {
    font-size: 30px;
    color: red;
    text-shadow: 1px 0 0 blue,-1px 0 0 blue, 0 1px 0 blue, 0 -1px 0 blue;
}
```

And HTML:

```
<span>Hello</span>
```